# Passing data from view in controller in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new to Zend and have a question regarding Zend Framework. I tried to google it but didn't get the right answer.

A previous developer did something like this in controller

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $abc = $this->view->abc;
}
```

My question is how can you assign something from view in a controller? If you can do so is this a legal assignment?

Comment: You only assign from controller to view, not from view to controller.

Comment: I know that you only assign from controller to view but my question was my previous developer did this so does this have any relavence in zend? or the whole assignment is wrong

Comment: But what's your question then? Doesn't it work?

Comment: it works fine and its all over the place my question is is this assignment legal? if the assignment possible?

Comment: @Kishore: legal in the sense of "it works" - yes; legal in the sense of good design: *NO*

Comment: I was actually wondering how can we get data from view and assign it in Controller but I guess Phil kind of answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst this is indeed a bad approach, I can provide a possible solution as to how this works.

My guess is, your previous developer is assigning some view properties early in the dispatch cycle, possibly even in Bootstrap, eg

```
// Bootstrap.php

protected function _initGlobalViewProperties()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->abc = 'abc';
}
```

Whilst there's really no issue with doing this, the view shouldn't be relied upon to *provide* resources to the controller. A better approach would be to create an application resource which is available to all controllers.

In `Bootstrap.php`...

```
protected function _initAbc()
{
    $resource = 'abc'; // can be anything

    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $view->abc = $resource;

    return $resource; // adds resource into Application registry
}
```

and in your controller...

```
$abc = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getResource('abc');
```